# Matlab DB Toolbox Reconfigured Fetch in Batches Option

Tags: mysql, matlab, fetch

Suddenly, with *no* apparent reason, all my `MYSQL` calls inside `MATLAB 2014b` such as:

```
conn = database('mysql','root',<mypssw>,'Vendor','MySQL','Server','localhost');
query='SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable;';
curs=exec(conn,query);
res=fetch(curs);
```

run under the following `Database Toolbox` warning:

> Warning: Unable to fetch in batches: Batch size
>   specified was larger than the number of rows fetched

The only previous antecedent is, several DB calls were executed one after other. [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/preference-settings-for-large-data-import.html) do not pronounce any sound opinion.

After the instruction:

```
setdbprefs('FetchInBatches','no');
```

-which, by the way, i never did care too much about it, after maybe the first usage of the Toolbox- the problem dissapeared, and the setting persisted under further `MATLAB` sessions and OS reboots.

Did anybody experienced this?. 
Can this suddenly happen again? 
Can `MATLAB` decides to reconfigure this option again, and thus paralyzing server side functionalities?

Comment: How many rows do you have? You are sure that all your data fits in the JVM heap?

Comment: Of course, mydb.mytable had only 10 rows!.... But maybe some temporary call possible exceed the JVM heap and MATLAB triggered the `SETDBPREFS`. But then, and after that, the warning was persistent until it is detected.

Comment: Did you try restarting Matlab to reset the JVM heap for the application?